# Is there any documentation how to implement custom authentication for web app -- azure app service?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

There are documentations for implementing custom authentication for mobile app -- azure app service, like this one:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#custom-auth

Are there any examples for web app, or does azure app service support custom authentication for web app?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have seen that one, too, and the custom auth leads to the link I posted in my question (mobile).